# How do I get a long listing for a single directory?

Tags: command-line, shell, ls

I want to see a long listing for a single directory. When I type `ls -lha`, I see this:

```
drwxrwxr-x  4 username groupname 4.0K 2010-08-05 09:55 files
drwxrwxr-x  7 username groupname 4.0K 2010-08-05 14:25 trunk
drwxrwxr-x  8 username groupname 4.0K 2010-08-05 16:02 phpincludes
drwxrwxr-x 11 username groupname 4.0K 2010-07-26 12:31 phpMyAdmin-3.3.5-english
```

However, when I type `ls -lha phpMyAdmin-3.3.5`, I get a listing of the contents of the directory. How do I type the command so that I see only

```
drwxrwxr-x 11 username groupname 4.0K 2010-07-26 12:31 phpMyAdmin-3.3.5-english
```

? I want to do this with symlinked directories, so I can see where they're linked to, not their contents.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
ls -lhad phpMyAdmin-3.3.5-english
```

The `-d` flag is used to tell `ls` that you want to show the properties of the given directory, not its contents.

Comment: This is basic stuff. Reading the manpage of the ls command is always a good idea.

Comment: So many man pages, so many switches. Sometimes the mind just glosses.

Comment: Don't read all the man pages and try to memorize everything at once. That's impossible. Instead, only try to read the man pages of commands you're having problems with, such as ls in this case.

Comment: Unix koan: How many lowercase letters are *invalid* switches to ls ?

Comment: @Kevin,Alex thanks for the help, but man pages are long, even for simple commands (on my screen, man ls is 5 screens -- is there a way to search in them?), and at the moment I need it, I don't want to learn the ins and outs of a command I'm having problems with, I just need to solve an immediate problem. Thus you scan, and sometimes you miss something.

Comment: In any case, from my `ls` man page, it says this for `-d`: `list directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links` -- now if you aren't applying your critical thinking skills, isn't the phrase "directory entries" a synonym for "directory contents"? In other words it's ambiguous, and the d switch is not *clearly* what I want, according to the man page. This entry was poorly written. Sometimes, sometimes, it's just better to ask someone than to look it up :)

Comment: @user394: "is there a way to search in them?" Yes. Press `/`, then enter a search term, then press return and man will jump to the first occurrence of the term in the manpage. You can then press `/` and return without a search term in between to jump to the next occurrence.

Comment: @sepp2k Of course, that behaviour is pager-specific. In most, you can also press `n` to go to the next occurrence.